# Setting up TTL on Azure Cosmos MongoDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I want to use mongoDB on Azure Cosmos. 
I need to set up partitions properly.
I need to implement TTL to delete documents older than one month.

I am currently creating the collection using this code:

```
var command = new JsonCommand<BsonDocument>("{ shardCollection: \"steps.steps\", key: { SlipID: \"hashed\" } }");
                db.RunCommand(command);
```

This creates the collection, and I can successfully insert documents into it. The code is based on this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data

Now I need to set up the TTL. On the azure portal, I go to the collection (under Data Explorer), and switch TTL to On, and save.

Now, when I try to insert a document into the collection I get this error: 
 `Command insert failed: PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation.`

Why?

EDIT: It looks like azure portal is removing the SlipID index when I save. When I add the index again, I can add documents again. How can I set TTL on a collection using the mongodb c# driver, without breaking anything else?

EDIT: Even when the index is recreated, I still get the above error periodically. I can see there are 10 partitions currently. I have a suspicion that the error happens when the new partition is created, and the first entry is inserted. I have no way to prove this through.

Comment: What value have you chosen for your partitionKey? Is it SlipId? What do you mean when you "add the index". Are you actually going into the Scale & Settings section and modifying the Indexing Policy by hand?

Comment: According to the documentation, the 'shardCollection' command above sets up sharding, and creates the index. So yes, SlipID is the index. 

I recreate the index by calling running this code from c#:
steps.Indexes.CreateOne(Builders<CosmosStep>.IndexKeys.Hashed(x => x.SlipID));